# Quadrapod vs Hexapod

Tags: mobile-robot, legged, hexapod

I want to build a robot, but I don't know if I want to build a quadrapod or a hexapod. I would like to use three servos/leg.

- Can you tell me what are the pros and cons of quadrapods compared to hexapods?

Comment: Your question *might* be considered a little broad, and primarily opinion based. However, it certainly is a question that I would like to know the answer to. Just a thought, are there two questions here? First you ask for the difference between a four and six legged robot (which `use three servos/leg`), but then you also say `What are the benefits of more servos/leg?` Are you also wishing to compare quad/hexapods with two or three servos per leg..?

Comment: I want to compare quadrapods with hexapods, from what I've seen on youtube quadrapods might be a little faster, and hexapods might be more stable when it comes to outdoors terrain and they can lift heavier things than quads. I've seen hexapods with 4 servos/leg but I don't know how is that better than 3 servos/leg.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* R. Barbus, but I'm afraid that questions asking for a list of pros and cons are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.